# Migrate Azure VM (domain joined) - another storage account

Tags: virtual-machine, migration, azure

I have an Azure LAB with DC running on a VM on Azure, call it "DC1". There is a VM joined to the domain say "VM1".

I stumbled across the post to migrate Azure VMs between storage accounts -> [Here](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/22/migrate-azure-virtual-machines-between-storage-accounts/)

Now before I go ahead and try to script the whole process, want to know if the below is feasible :

1. Copy the existing VHD blobs for OS disk to the Destination Storage Account.
2. Create Azure Disks from the migrated VHDs (specifying it is OS disk).
3. Remove the Old "VM1"
4. Provision a new VM having the same configuration as the old VM1.

I suspect this is not feasible but I have heard that one can simply upload the on-premise (domain joined) workloads into Azure and run them seamlessly provided networking to the on-prem is setup correctly.

Thanks for taking time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to create the new disks from VHD. You can initiate the blob transfer directly in Azure (`start-azurestorageblobcopy`), no need to download and re-upload the VHD.

When you copy the blobs to the new storage account you can create a new VM configuration and attach those blobs as the VM disks.  You can then provision and start the VM.  As long as it is in same subscription you can re-attach existing NIC's as well and it will start right up.